Google Cloud Network Load Balancer not created by Istio ingress controller in GKE Enterprise cluster
According to the GKE Enterprise Knative docs

When your GKE Enterprise cluster is created, the Istio ingress controller creates a Google Cloud Network Load Balancer with a publicly available IP address.

However I do not see any Load Balancer created in any namespace.
> kubectl get -A svc
NAMESPACE         NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                            PORT(S)                                     AGE
ai-knative        hello                        ExternalName   <none>           knative-local-gateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local   80/TCP                                      42m
ai-knative        hello-00001-tah              ClusterIP      34.118.235.136   <none>                                                 80/TCP,443/TCP                              45m
ai-knative        hello-00001-tah-private      ClusterIP      34.118.237.41    <none>                                                 80/TCP,443/TCP,9090/TCP,9091/TCP,8022/TCP   45m
default           hello2                       ExternalName   <none>           knative-local-gateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local   80/TCP                                      30m
default           hello2-00001-zeq             ClusterIP      34.118.236.206   <none>                                                 80/TCP,443/TCP                              33m
default           hello2-00001-zeq-private     ClusterIP      34.118.236.251   <none>                                                 80/TCP,443/TCP,9090/TCP,9091/TCP,8022/TCP   33m
default           kubernetes                   ClusterIP      34.118.224.1     <none>                                                 443/TCP                                     93m
gke-gmp-system    alertmanager                 ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                 9093/TCP                                    91m
gke-gmp-system    gmp-operator                 ClusterIP      34.118.237.92    <none>                                                 8443/TCP,443/TCP                            91m
istio-system      knative-local-gateway        ClusterIP      34.118.239.241   <none>                                                 80/TCP                                      65m
knative-serving   activator-service            ClusterIP      34.118.235.8     <none>                                                 9090/TCP,8008/TCP,80/TCP,81/TCP,443/TCP     65m
knative-serving   autoscaler                   ClusterIP      34.118.230.158   <none>                                                 9090/TCP,8008/TCP,8080/TCP                  65m
knative-serving   autoscaler-bucket-00-of-01   ClusterIP      34.118.232.176   <none>                                                 8080/TCP                                    62m
knative-serving   controller                   ClusterIP      34.118.227.206   <none>                                                 9090/TCP,8008/TCP                           65m
knative-serving   metrics-collector            ClusterIP      34.118.227.30    <none>                                                 55678/TCP                                   65m
knative-serving   webhook                      ClusterIP      34.118.235.168   <none>                                                 9090/TCP,8008/TCP,443/TCP                   65m
kube-system       antrea                       ClusterIP      34.118.234.127   <none>                                                 443/TCP                                     91m
kube-system       default-http-backend         NodePort       34.118.239.110   <none>                                                 80:32319/TCP                                91m
kube-system       kube-dns                     ClusterIP      34.118.224.10    <none>                                                 53/UDP,53/TCP                               92m
kube-system       metrics-server               ClusterIP      34.118.238.69    <none>                                                 443/TCP                                     91m

Fleet Mesh:
fleetDefaultMemberConfig:
  mesh:
    management: MANAGEMENT_AUTOMATIC
membershipSpecs:
  projects/<project number>/locations/us-central1/memberships/cloudrun:
    mesh:
      management: MANAGEMENT_AUTOMATIC
    origin:
      type: FLEET
membershipStates:
  projects/<project number>/locations/us-central1/memberships/cloudrun:
    servicemesh:
      conditions:
      - code: VPCSC_GA_SUPPORTED
        details: This control plane supports VPC-SC GA.
        documentationLink: http://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/managed/vpc-sc
        severity: INFO
      controlPlaneManagement:
        details:
        - code: REVISION_READY
          details: 'Ready: asm-managed'
        implementation: ISTIOD
        state: ACTIVE
      dataPlaneManagement:
        details:
        - code: OK
          details: Service is running.
        state: ACTIVE
    state:
      code: OK
      description: |-
        Revision ready for use: asm-managed.
        All Canonical Services have been reconciled successfully.
      updateTime: '2024-07-25T13:48:33.036470227Z'
name: projects/<project id>/locations/global/features/servicemesh
resourceState:
  state: ACTIVE

If I need to manually create this what would the spec look like?
Are any other services missing?
